# Как защитить от реверсинга получение пути вызывающего приложения?

Tags: c++, c, защита, взлом

Есть некая нативная функция, которую вызывает управляемое приложение.
В этой функции следующий код получает путь вызывающего приложения:

```
    std::wstring fileExecutePath; 
    LPWSTR *szArglist; 
    int nArgs = 0;
    szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs);
    if (szArglist != NULL) 
        fileExecutePath = szArglist[0];
    LocalFree(szArglist);
```

Может ли реверсер подменить этот путь, и как от этого защититься?

Comment: Мне кажется подменить можно любой пусть. Вы же можете усложнить задачу, чтобы потенциальный взломщик бросил это дело.

Comment: @Unick, есть ли какой либо обходной путь получения пути вызывающего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, никак.
Но есть разные способы усложнить задачу злоумышленнику.

1) Обфускаторы - добавляют в код кучу мусора, чтобы усложнить поиск логики в дизассемблированном коде. Относительно бесполезны, особенно если крякер попадется с опытом. Сильно сказываются на производительности.

2) Шифровальщики - предотвращают запуск/исследование без ключа. Полностью бесполезны, т.к. ключ наверняка утечет вместе с софтом. Аппаратный ключ тоже не спасет - они легко эмулируются.

3) Хеширование - можно запретить запуск приложения, если его код был изменен. Но эту логику можно обойти точно так же, как и логику проверки пути вызывающего приложения.

Если подойти к делу комплексно, можно замедлить взлом на порядок, а то и вовсе отбить желание возиться с этим.

Если же речь идет о защите пользователя, а не о защите от пользователя, то можно просто попросить/заставить его установить и запускать приложение с желаемыми правами/ограничениями, чтобы никакой зловред ничего не подменил.

Comment: А, допустим, если реверсер не имеет доступа к нативному коду и не может предотвратить вызовы CommandLineToArgvW и GetCommandLineW(), он можешь их эмулировать и через них передать подмененный путь? Про обфуксаторы, протекторы и проверку хешей понятно.

Comment: Тут вариантов просто масса. Во-первых можно просто положить по нужному пути что-нибудь своё, что вполне законно передаст правильный путь. Во-вторых можно просто записать в кучу нужную строку, и прямо в стеке подменить указатель непосредственно после вызова CommandLineToArgvW. В-третьих можно просто подменить либу, в которой объявлены эти функции, на что-нибудь своё. И это так, на вскидку. Думаю, много чего еще можно придумать..

Comment: Возможно, есть какие либо малоизвестные варианты получить caller path? Не встречали подобного?

Comment: Не встречал, но я особо и не искал ) Вообще, когда Вы занимаетесь разработкой DRM и подобных вещей, нужно понимать одну важную вещь - Вас обязательно взломают. И именно это - главная проблема. Если контент предполагает его использование на машине потенциального взломщика - он не может быть защищен, а взлом - всего лишь вопрос времени. Лучше вообще не тратить на это деньги. Дешевле выйдет.